# Angular freezes for a while, when it updates the scope. How to handle that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Well, has been a while since I'm trying to make a really fluid ajax call behind the scenes, every seconds, to make my app work in real-time.

It seems that the application is freezing while it is updating the scope inside the $http .then();

```
$http.get('path/to/script.php?user_id='+userId)
.then( function(data){
      $scope.mydata = data
})
```

If I'm just going to comment the `//$scope.mydata=data` then everything seems to work fine, no freezing, everything is smooth and quiet.

Any idea how to bypass this problem?
Thanks in advance :)

---

### EDIT:

the controller to update the $scope is like this:

```
function getTasks(){
//first we add the Starting unix date
var sDateHour = $scope.hoursInterval[0].sUnix;
var eDateHour = $scope.hoursInterval[$scope.hoursInterval.length-1].eUnix;

$http.get('php/api/file/(filename).php?getTasks=1&sDH='+sDateHour+"&eDH="+eDateHour)
      .then(function(data){
          var datas = data.data;
          $scope.proftask =datas;
          $scope.loadingBar=false;
  });
}
```

**Here's my HTML Table where I'm binding those datas**

```
<table class="fwidthTable{{gr.id_groupe}} countTable table table-hover" style="display:none;"
              ng-class="{'{{gr.id_groupe}}': gr.id_groupe>=0}" >
                <thead class="table-bordered" style="background:rgb(109, 142, 221);color:#FFF;">
                  <tr><td class="toggleHeadTable" colspan="{{profiles.length+1}}"
                    ng-click="toggleTable(gr.id_groupe)" align="center">{{gr.libelle}}</td></tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class="horraires">
                        Horraires
                      </td>
                      <td ng-repeat="pr in profiles"
                      class="tdVerticalNames" ng-if="gr.id_groupe==pr.groupe"
                      align="center" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bolder">
                      {{pr.nom | limitTo: 10}}<br />{{pr.prenom}} <br />{{pr.taux}}%</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody class="table-bordered" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:300px;padding-bottom:50px;">
                  <tr class="totalHours">
                    <td align="right">Total Heures:</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="pr in profiles"
                    ng-if="gr.id_groupe==pr.groupe"></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr ng-repeat="hr in hoursInterval" ng-class="{'dayBreak': hr.sHour>'11:30' && hr.eHour<'13:30'}">

                    <td style="width:200px !important;" class="horraires"  ng-class="{'dayBreak': hr.sHour>'11:30' && hr.eHour<'13:30'}"
                      align="center" >{{hr.sHour}} - {{hr.eHour}}</td>

                    <td ng-repeat="pt in proftask" ng-if="gr.id_groupe==pt.groupe" class="tableCell{{pt.id_profile}}{{hr.id}}"
                    onclick="updateCell(this)" ng-click="getTimeInterval(hr.sUnix,hr.eUnix,pt.id_profile)">
                      <label ng-repeat="t in pt.tasks"
                      ng-if="t.date_heure_deb==hr.sUnix && t.date_heure_fin==hr.eUnix" ng-bind="t.libelle"></label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

**This is the data I'm getting from the server**

Array of -> (91)

```
0: {id_profile: "1", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69826"}
1: {id_profile: "2", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69827"}
2: {id_profile: "3", groupe: "3", tasks: Array(8), $$hashKey: "object:69828"}
3: {id_profile: "4", groupe: "3", tasks: Array(8), $$hashKey: "object:69829"}
4: {id_profile: "5", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69830"}
5: {id_profile: "6", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69831"}
6: {id_profile: "7", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69832"}
7: {id_profile: "8", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69833"}
8: {id_profile: "9", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69834"}
9: {id_profile: "10", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69835"}
10: {id_profile: "14", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69836"}
11: {id_profile: "15", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69837"}
12: {id_profile: "16", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69838"}
13: {id_profile: "17", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69839"}
14: {id_profile: "18", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69840"}
15: {id_profile: "19", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69841"}
16: {id_profile: "20", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69842"}
17: {id_profile: "21", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69843"}
18: {id_profile: "22", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69844"}
19: {id_profile: "23", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69845"}
20: {id_profile: "24", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69846"}
21: {id_profile: "25", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69847"}
22: {id_profile: "26", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69848"}
23: {id_profile: "27", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69849"}
24: {id_profile: "28", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69850"}
25: {id_profile: "29", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69851"}
26: {id_profile: "30", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69852"}
27: {id_profile: "31", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69853"}
28: {id_profile: "32", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69854"}
29: {id_profile: "33", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69855"}
30: {id_profile: "34", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69856"}
31: {id_profile: "35", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69857"}32: {id_profile: "38", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69858"}33: {id_profile: "42", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69859"}34: {id_profile: "36", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69860"}35: {id_profile: "37", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69861"}36: {id_profile: "39", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69862"}37: {id_profile: "40", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69863"}38: {id_profile: "41", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69864"}39: {id_profile: "43", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69865"}40: {id_profile: "44", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69866"}41: {id_profile: "45", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69867"}42: {id_profile: "46", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69868"}43: {id_profile: "47", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69869"}44: {id_profile: "48", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69870"}45: {id_profile: "49", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69871"}46: {id_profile: "50", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69872"}47: {id_profile: "51", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69873"}48: {id_profile: "52", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69874"}49: {id_profile: "53", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69875"}50: {id_profile: "54", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69876"}51: {id_profile: "55", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69877"}52: {id_profile: "56", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69878"}53: {id_profile: "57", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69879"}54: {id_profile: "58", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69880"}55: {id_profile: "59", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69881"}56: {id_profile: "77", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69882"}57: {id_profile: "60", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69883"}58: {id_profile: "61", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69884"}59: {id_profile: "62", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69885"}60: {id_profile: "63", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69886"}61: {id_profile: "64", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69887"}62: {id_profile: "65", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69888"}63: {id_profile: "66", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69889"}64: {id_profile: "67", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69890"}65: {id_profile: "68", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69891"}66: {id_profile: "69", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69892"}67: {id_profile: "70", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69893"}68: {id_profile: "71", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69894"}69: {id_profile: "72", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69895"}70: {id_profile: "73", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69896"}71: {id_profile: "74", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69897"}72: {id_profile: "75", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69898"}73: {id_profile: "76", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69899"}74: {id_profile: "78", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69900"}75: {id_profile: "79", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69901"}76: {id_profile: "80", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69902"}77: {id_profile: "81", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69903"}78: {id_profile: "82", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69904"}79: {id_profile: "83", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69905"}80: {id_profile: "84", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69906"}81: {id_profile: "85", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69907"}82: {id_profile: "86", groupe: "1", $$hashKey: "object:69908"}83: {id_profile: "87", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69909"}84: {id_profile: "88", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69910"}85: {id_profile: "89", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69911"}86: {id_profile: "90", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69912"}87: {id_profile: "91", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69913"}88: {id_profile: "92", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69914"}89: {id_profile: "93", groupe: "0", $$hashKey: "object:69915"}90: {id_profile: "94", groupe: "3", $$hashKey: "object:69916"}
```

length: 91__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: How much data is coming thru that AJAX call?

Comment: No problem here, I used to wrap updated scope declaration inside a setTimeout of 0 sometimes, but your code here is not a cause of bug.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: tymeJV -
Is a normal json, containing the TODO of the current day,
almost 834B - 1000b each time. but it doesn't really matter how much data,
it can download with ajax without even affecting the UI. It happens only when updating the SCOPE with new data

Comment: Well it could be anything that causes it to freeze up in how you bind the data, to how it is looped, etc

Comment: What are you doing with the data? There are a number of things that could be causing application lag.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add your controller and html code that deals with this data. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and especially read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello guys, please check my updated Question.
Thanks to all

Comment: @DuliNini Can you also add the HTML that is using `$scope.proftask`. Assigning the response data to a variable should cause lag to the extent you describe in your question, problems like you are seeing are usually from the way the data is being rendered or filtered.

Comment: @Tyler   I will write the Table here, but since there's a table with dynamically rendered columns and rows, I had to use multiple ng-repeat..
Give me 1 minute please

Comment: @DuliNini That is fine, it is probably what is causing your issues as well, so hopefully we can clean it up and make it easier to read and quicker to render

Comment: @DuliNini Can you also post an example of what the data you are receiving looks like?

Comment: @Tyler   Yes now you have the data I'm getting from the server. Please help me out

Comment: @georgeawg   So I should remove the onclick from there and add the jquery function on angular?
Would that solve?
Thank you

Comment: @georgeawg  No it doesn't make any difference even if I remove the onclick

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.  jQuery functions that operate outside the AngularJS framework need to be handled in a structured way which is beyond the scoe of the question. Re-ask the question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Writing this as an answer, cause comment does not have enough space:

it is hard to see how complex your final html looks like and how many elements also because there is no indication of how large your intervals are. But, it seems that at least you have 91 profile and some intervals and tasks. I figure, that your html is fairly large. Angularjs and large complex html are not a good combination in my experience. You should limit the amount of bound elements for best performance, since every $digest cycle will update anything that is bound and in dom. And digest cycles do happen after every http call or timeout events if I recall correctly.

Another thing that I've noticed when I have opened your app is that in element inspector it seems to update the whole page constantly. And that is because you seem to call getTask.php a number of times. Well... each time you execute a XHR call your whole huge page gets $digested. I am running on pretty fast machine, so I didn't notice too much of a freeze. But due to that calls and refreshing your application eats 10% of i7-7700K CPU for 12 seconds. That is quite a bit. So, I think, it is the real issue that causes the freeze.

Imho, you need to restructure your app. 
 - limit the amount of items you render to the page. see if paging will work for for you for example. 
 - load tasks data before you render the view, so that you dont have to do digests on this monster DOM. use something like ui-router to make your application more of a state machine. it allows you to resolve data before you enter a state.

Angular1 is a good and powerful framework to use, but it is easy to misuse and end up with poorly performing app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm trying to determine how does that re-renders every thing in my DOM? Because I'm updating only the $scope.proftask  and not the whole DOM!!

Comment: It does not re-render everything, but those items which are touched by the updated scope or bound by methods i.e. ng-if="checkMe()" will get called with every digest. Scoped variables update could be enough to trigger lots of updates if you have many elements bound to those. And you seem to have alot. That is why it looks like so many elements are being updated.

Comment: Ahh great, I see my problem now. 
Since I'm just hiding tables, this still makes update on 2-3 hidden tables.

Right, now I have just to take data for the single table. It may produce faster results then

Comment: Great answer, I completely agree, just wanted to add one thing, the `$digest` cycle happens even more frequently than you stated. It happens every time a value on the `$scope` could have been changed, so any `ng-click`, `ng-change`, typing into input tied to `ng-model`, etc.

Comment: @Tyler
I tried almos all things but the delay is when I attach data to $scope,
NOT when fetching the data from server

Comment: I understand, `$digest` has nothing to do with the server, I was just pointing out that the `$digest` cycle happens even more often than Vladimir pointed out. Having too many variables to update or filters to run in each "`$digest` cycle" is usually what leads to pages being unresponsive or laggy.